# CodeIgniter inserting data into database after submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

below is my `books_controller.php`

```
function books_s()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->model('books_model');

    $sri=$this->input->post();
    print_R($sri);

    if($this->input->post())
    {
    $bookme=$this->load->books_model->post_books(); 

    }
    $this->load->view('header.php');    
}
```

i have not placed my `books_view.php` code bcos you can see in my controller code i have done `print_R($sri);` i can see the the values are posted from view page to controller page ...out put is

```
Array ( 
    [Id] => 4 
    [title] => just testng 
    [text] => goooo 
    [submit] => submit 
    )
```

` iam also getting error message

`Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$books_model`

`Filename: controllers/books_Controller.php` 
`books_controller.php`   i know its an issue with my model code

```
function books_model()
{
    parent::__Construct();
}

function post_books()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $title=$this->input->post('title');
    $text=$this->input->post('text');

    $data=array('id'=>$id,'title'=>$title,'text'=>$text);
    $this->db->insert('data',$data);
}
```

Can you guys help me to find where am I doing the mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bookme=$this->load->books_model->post_books();
```

You have already loaded the model, so now you just need to access the instance so it should be:

```
$bookme=$this->books_model->post_books();
```

You also need to do this:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

However, it should not really be the thing causing the error as it should work either way, but the above is the correct way.

Comment: hmmm i got it cryptic....,,very silly mistake ..:(.... problem solved.. thanks dear...

Comment: @user1659450, you're welcome. It's always the small things that cause the headaches =o)

Answer (score 2):

Your model should be like this

```
Class Books_Model Extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function post_books()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $title=$this->input->post('title');
        $text=$this->input->post('text');

        $data=array('id'=>$id,'title'=>$title,'text'=>$text);
        $this->db->insert('data',$data);
    }
}
```